# In R: find out of order (non ascending) elements in a vector and interpolate

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which one vector has some elements "mismatched". I need them to be in the "right order", without disturbing the other vectors.

This is an example df:

```
df <- data.frame("distance" = c(2, 5, 7, 10, 25, 15, 18, 22, 11, 27, 31),
             "v" = c(100, 100, 102, 101, 100, 99, 96, 90, 87, 85, 80))
```

In the vector "distance"  the elements 25 and 11 are mismatched, because the entire vector needs to be in ascending order. I need two things: a way to identify 25 and 11 as "wrong", and a way to interpolate a new element there in order to gain the following df1:

```
df1 <- data.frame("distance" = c(2, 5, 7, 10, 13, 15, 18, 22, 25, 27, 31),
              "v" = c(100, 100, 102, 101, 100, 99, 96, 90, 87, 85, 80))
```

Checking for ascending or descending won't work because it could be right or wrong, so I am a bit stuck. Can you help me?

Best regards,

Johan

Comment: You'll need to define how to determine whether `distance` should be sorted in ascending or descending order and how to handle edge cases.  For example, with ascending `distance`, how would you handle the case when the last three `distance`s are `11`, `27`, and `22`?

Comment: Wouldn't just sorting `distance` column work? `df$distance <- sort(df$distance)`

Comment: Sorting wouldn't work in all situations. It could be that only one element is misplaced. This mixes up the values in the other vecors which are matched.

Comment: ```Distance``` needs to be ascending. I'm assuming the edges have at least 5 or more elements which are ascending in the right manner. The mismatches are located in the middle of a vector with length of about 100 elements.

Comment: Perhaps check whether the distance is in the range of (-1, 5). If it is not, than it is not in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way would be to do the linear interpolation on the entire column. This would work as long as "wrong" values only appear infrequently.

```
df <- data.frame("distance" = c(2, 5, 7, 10, 25, 15, 18, 22, 11, 27, 31),
                 "v" = c(100, 100, 102, 101, 100, 99, 96, 90, 87, 85, 80))

#The code below assumes that first and last distance in df are not mismatched
monotonize <- function(vec){
  vec_org <- vec #original vector
  index <- 1:length(vec)
  diff_vec_previous <- c(0,diff(vec))
  diff_vec_next <- rev(c(0,diff(rev(vec))))
  #each element of vec should be larger than previous element and smaller than next element
  #if both conditions not satisfied, it is defined as aberration
  aberrations <- diff_vec_previous < 0 | diff_vec_next > 0
  if(TRUE %in% aberrations) {
    x <- index[!aberrations]
    y <- vec[!aberrations]
    xout <- index[aberrations]
    vec[aberrations] <- approx(x,y,xout)$y #linear interpolation
    #one by one we try replacing the elements with the original vector 
    #so that only real aberrations are modified
    for (i in 1:length(xout)) {
      ind <- xout[i]
      vec_tmp <- vec
      vec_tmp[ind] <- vec_org[ind]
      aberrations_tmp <- c(0,diff(vec_tmp)) < 0 | rev(c(0,diff(rev(vec_tmp)))) > 0
      if(! TRUE %in% aberrations_tmp){
        vec <- vec_tmp
      }
    }
  }
  return(vec)
}

df$distance <- monotonize(df$distance)
#you can convert the replaced distances to integers if you wish
```